# Pulling a remote windows server architecture in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have the following code. I am trying to get the information on whether or not the remote computer I am connecting to is 32-bit or 64 bit. I tried doing it at the last snippet of this code but it didn't work. Here is the error (I changed the remote system name):

> WshShell.RegRead: Invalid root in registry key
>   "\*remotesystem*\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentCon
>   trolSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE".

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWMISrvc,strRemoteComputer,colOSItems,objItem,args,OsType

'String variables
Dim strName,strCaption,strVersion,strCSDVer,strSerial,WshShell

'Adding this in to transfer FQDN variable to this script from ASP.net
Set args = WScript.Arguments
strRemoteComputer = args.Item(0)

Set objWMISrvc = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strRemoteComputer & "\root\cimv2")


CheckOSType objWMISrvc


Sub CheckOSType( objWMISrvc )
        Set colOSItems = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
        For Each objItem in colOSItems
            strName = objItem.CSName 
            'strDesc = objItem.Description 
            'strManufac = objItem.Manufacturer 
            strCaption = objItem.Caption 
            strVersion = objItem.Version 
            strCSDVer = objItem.CSDVersion 
            strSerial = objItem.SerialNumber 
        Next


        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        OsType = WshShell.RegRead("\\" & strRemoteComputer & "\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
        If OsType = "x86" then
            WScript.Echo "Windows 32bit system detected"
        elseif OsType = "AMD64" then
            WScript.Echo "Windows 64bit system detected"
        end if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly from WMI without reading the registry.  Just loop through your computer names with this script.  It returns either "32" or "64".

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmt:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessors = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

For Each objProcessor in colProcessors
    WScript.Echo objProcessor.AddressWidth     'or  objProcessor.DataWidth
    Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

To read the registry of as remote machine you must use the the [`StdRegProv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class

Check this sample

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject( _
   "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
strValueName = "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"
oReg.GetStringValue _
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,OsType
WScript.Echo  OsType
```